# How to bind array of inputs checkbox when adding and updating

Tags: html, arrays, angular, checkbox

I have an array with default values that are being used when creating a customer. By default, all the checkboxes(50,70,90) will be pre-selected from the back-end but not visible on the UI when adding a customer. But, when you edit, it must display all the checkboxes and the user can either un-check (50, 70, or 90%) and then update.

Process:

On Add customer:

1. Create customer
2. by default(you will have 3 checkboxes) from the view but hidden
3. All checkboxes will be selected (50,70 and 90%)
4. A user won't see the checkboxes as they are hidden.
5. User will see the checkbox on edit only.
6. Save info

Update:

1. from the view display/bind three checkboxes
2. All checkboxes will be selected because, on add, we have set them on the array.
3. A user will have the option to un-tick either (50,70, or 90%) checkboxes
4. And save with the new updated checkbox selection.

Thanks for your help

**ts. My Object**

```
    public newCustomer: any = {
    cont1: undefined,
    --
    --
    balance: 0.0,
    credit_limit_warning: [
        {
            type: "P",
            warning_threshold: 50,
        },
        {
            type: "P",
            warning_threshold: 70,
        },
        {
            type: "P",
            warning_threshold: 90,
        }
    ]
};
```

**HTML** : This is what i have tried on **Adding** but not working.

```
     <div class="row" hidden>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-12">
                <p class="color-white-60">
                    Notifications<br>
                    <small style="font-size: 12px;">(% of Credit Limit)</small>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div *ngFor="let item of credit_limit_warning; let i = index;" hidden>
                {{i}}
                <span style="padding-right: 10px;"> <input (click)="setCustomerCreditLimitWarning(50, false)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="'creditWarning50 + i'" [(ngModel)]="item.credit_limit_warning"/><label> 50 % </label></span>
                <span style="padding-right: 10px;"> <input (click)="setCustomerCreditLimitWarning(70, false)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" [name]="'creditWarning70' + i" [(ngModel)]="item.credit_limit_warning"/><label> 70 % </label></span>
                <span style="padding-right: 10px;"> <input (click)="setCustomerCreditLimitWarning(90, false)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" [name]="'creditWarning90' + i" [(ngModel)]="item.credit_limit_warning"/><label> 90 % </label></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**HTML Update**: this is the update html and i am not sure how i can tackle this.

```
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
                                <p class="color-white-60">
                                    Contact Number
                                </p>
                                <input [(ngModel)]="customer.cont1" name="contactNumberEdit" placeholder="Contact Number" formControlName="contactNumber" class="form-control" type="text">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row" >
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-12" >
                                    <p class="color-white-60">
                                        Usage Notifications<br>
                                        <small style="font-size: 12px;">(% of Credit Limit)</small>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-12 mt-10" >
                                    <span style="padding-right: 10px;"> <input name="usageNotification" formControlName="usageNotification" (click)="setCustomerCreditLimitWarning(50, false)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /><label> 50 % </label></span>
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but first of all - why is it checkbox and not radio?

Comment: I have 3 checkboxes(50,70 and 90%) that I want to save when adding a customer. I have defined my array of objects. When creating a customer, you won't have to tick all three check boxes as the process is done on back end.

On Edit: Display checkboxes which we saved by default. A customer can either uncheck one of the checkboxes  and click save

Comment: @RoboRobok I have added a bit of process flow of what i want. thanks

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you for getting back to me. I am dealing with another problem of multiple emails input in angular

Comment: Post it on SO if necessary and comment here if nobody replies, so I'd help :)

Comment: Ok, i will post it shortly so that you can respond